# would like to know if variables from the outer quantifier level are accessible in the inner quantifier level

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using nested quantifiers (Forall, Exists) and would like to know if variables from the outer quantifier level are accessible in the inner quantifier level. For example in the code below does the variable "pack" have the same value throughout the constraint? In other words, in the Exists quantifier level when "pack" is used, does it have the same value as "pack" in the first half of the implication.

If not, how can I specify that they both refer to the same variable or value?

```
s.add(Implies(constraint17a,
          ForAll((t,p,pack),
                 Implies(And(knows(t+1,p,pack)==True,knows(t,p,pack)==False,pack>0,p>0,t>=0,p<=2,t<=16,pack<=2),#if process p knows a packet now and did not know it in previous step
                         And(listen(t,p)==True,                                                                 #then p listened in the previous step,
                             Exists(q,And(q<p,q>=0,q<=2,transmit(t,q)==pack)),                                  #another process q transmitted that packet in the previous step
                             ForAll(q1,Implies(And(not(q1==p),not(q1==q),q1>=0,q1<=2),transmit(t,q1)==-1))      #and no other process q1 except q was transmitting in previous step
                             )
                         )
                 )
          )
  )
```

Comment: Is this Python code? Generally, Z3 uses de-Brujin indexes for variables, the names are only for humans and they are not used to identify variables. You can print the body of a quantifier (only the body!) and those variables bound by quantifiers on the outside will be shown as variable-indexes instead of names.

Comment: Christoph - Yes this is python code. I am new to z3py and trying to use it for my project, so i think i only understood your comment partially (little bit). Just to clarify what i understood, variables outside quantifiers cannot be accessed via names or their values will not be same when accessed via names since they are in two different quantifiers.

Comment: Quantified variables in any Z3 code are indexed by de-Brujin indexes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index i.e. they have numbers. The names like "pack" are only for human readability, the only time at which Z3 actually uses them, is when it has to print expressions. If you print only the body of the quantifier, those names are not available to the printer, and it will print the indexes instead.

Comment: Below is another small chunk of code to explain better what I would like to understand.

Do you think value of pack in **knows(t+1,p,pack)** is same as pack in **transmit(t,q)== pack**

for e.g. is pack = 1 in both  locations


    `for t in range(0, 3):
  for p in range(1,2):
   for pack in range(1, 2):
    for q in range(0,p):
      s.add(Implies(constraint17a,              
     Implies(And(knows(t+1,p,pack) ==True, knows(t,p,pack)==False),
      And(transmit(t,q)== pack, listen(t,p)==True)
 )                     
 )
 )`

Comment: There are no quantifiers, everything is implicitly outer-most existential, so yes, they are the same.